# How to customize default wordpress editor?

Tags: wordpress, editor, customization

Good to hear that Sony (wordpress3.3) has the new editor api [**wp_editor()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) that gives us the ability to use multiple instances of the editor in our custom fields with ease.

But I needed to to customize the default editor (for the main content) and couldn't figure out how to do it with this function.
I needed to customize the editor for the my new custom post type called *baner* for which i needed to change the size of the editor with fewer buttons. I know i could do it by simply using a custom field instead but for some reason i want to use the content for the description of the banner.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to place custom metabox above the default editor and i've found the solution to my old question (how to customize the default editor with the wp_editor)!

The solution was to unset the default editor first. Then create another metabox to to place the content then use wp_editor to create new its new instance, simple isn't it?

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'page_meta_boxes' );
public function page_meta_boxes()
{

    global $_wp_post_type_features;
            //ive defined my other metaboxes first with higher priority
    add_meta_box(
        $id     =   'page_heading_meta_box',
        $title  =   __('Heading'),
        $callback   = array(&$this,'render_page_heading_metabox'),
        $post_type  =   'page',
        $context    =   'normal',
        $priority   =   'core'
        );
    add_meta_box(
        $id     =   'page_description_meta_box',
        $title  =   __('Description'),
        $callback   = array(&$this,'render_page_description_metabox'),
        $post_type  =   'page',
        $context    =   'normal',
        $priority   =   'core'
        );
    //check for the required post type page or post or <custom post type(here article)  
    if (isset($_wp_post_type_features['article']['editor']) && $_wp_post_type_features['post']['editor']) {
        unset($_wp_post_type_features['article']['editor']);
        add_meta_box(
            'wsp_content',
            __('Content'),
            array(&$this,'content_editor_meta_box'),
            'article', 'normal', 'core'
        );
    }
    if (isset($_wp_post_type_features['page']['editor']) && $_wp_post_type_features['page']['editor']) {
        unset($_wp_post_type_features['page']['editor']);
        add_meta_box(
            'wsp_content',
            __('Content'),
            array(&$this,'content_editor_meta_box'),
            'page', 'normal', 'low'
        );
    }
    }
```

In this way we have registered a new metabox called content . Now time to place the editor

```
        function content_editor_meta_box($post)
    {
        $settings = array(
            #media_buttons
            #(boolean) (optional) Whether to display media insert/upload buttons
            #Default: true
            'media_buttons' => true,

            #textarea_name
            #(string) (optional) The name assigned to the generated textarea and passed parameter when the form is submitted. (may include [] to pass data as array)
            #Default: $editor_id
            'textarea_name'=>'content',

            #textarea_rows
            #(integer) (optional) The number of rows to display for the textarea
            #Default: get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10)

            #tabindex
            #(integer) (optional) The tabindex value used for the form field
            #Default: None
            'tabindex' => '4'

            #editor_css
            #(string) (optional) Additional CSS styling applied for both visual and HTML editors buttons, needs to #include <style> tags, can use "scoped"
            #Default: None

            #editor_class
            #(string) (optional) Any extra CSS Classes to append to the Editor textarea
            #Default:

            #teeny
            #(boolean) (optional) Whether to output the minimal editor configuration used in PressThis
            #Default: false

            #dfw
            #(boolean) (optional) Whether to replace the default fullscreen editor with DFW (needs specific DOM elements #and css)
            #Default: false

            #tinymce
            #(array) (optional) Load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()
            #Default: true

            #quicktags
            #(array) (optional) Load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array()
            #Default: true
        );
        wp_editor($post->post_content,'content');

    }
```

Now you can fully customize your editor! This is how it looks now. Hope it is useful for you too!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the editor (TinyMCE) with a filter, as shown [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE). Code snippet attached:

```
function myformatTinyMCE($in)
{
 $in['plugins']='inlinepopups,tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpfullscreen';
 $in['wpautop']=true;
 $in['apply_source_formatting']=false;
 $in['theme_advanced_buttons1']='formatselect,forecolor,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv';
 $in['theme_advanced_buttons2']='pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,|,charmap,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo';
 $in['theme_advanced_buttons3']='';
 $in['theme_advanced_buttons4']='';
 return $in;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

This code should be placed in your theme's `functions.php` file. You may want to `print_r( $in )` to see all the keys that are passed (I've omitted some of them here because I don't believe the page that I linked to above is up-to-date). You can browse the latest source [here](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/3.3/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php). You'll find the filters you're looking for in function `public static function editor_settings($editor_id, $set)`

Also, you may also want to make sure that this only happens for your `baner` post_type, as this will affect all instances of the editor that are created.

Comment: I'd tried this but i didn't find any  options like changing the editor size(ie textarea_rows) , making it teeny etc.

Comment: You linked to the wp_editor reference in your initial question -- you can modify these options via the `$settings` parameter with keys `textarea_rows` and `teeny`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-edit/) which you can add additional fields also it is simple to use and install

Comment: It was kind of heavy, with extra tables, i didn't like that, anyway thanks for the suggestion.